# How do I make a system call and resume execution without waiting for the call to return?

Tags: perl, system-calls

Basically I want to use system(), exec(), back-ticks or something to make a system call, but then to immediately resume execution in the calling script without caring about the result of the call and whether or not it returns, dies, stalls, whatever.

Is it possible to do this without threading/forking?

Comment: Are you on unix?  then start your command as a background process:  `system('command > /dev/null &')`.  Also check out: [`Running job in the background from Perl WITHOUT waiting for return`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646694/running-job-in-the-background-from-perl-without-waiting-for-return)

Comment: Yeah, I'm running lubuntu.

`/dev/null 2>&1 &` seems to have done the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, no. This is the entire *point* of `fork()`. The only question is whether you call `fork()` directly, or get something else to do that for you.

As mentioned, you could use the shell's backgrounding operator (`&`) to do that, but then you're using the shell, and that comes with the usual string-injection attack problem

```
system("some command with args &");
```

More directly, you could just do the usual `fork()` and `exec()` and then not perform the `waitpid()` that normally happens, which is where the blocking occurs:

```
if(fork() == 0) {
  exec("some", "command", "with", "args") or die "Cannot exec - $!";
}
# No waitpid here so no waiting
```

If you're doing that, best also to put a `SIGCHLD` handler in to ignore when the child does eventually exit, so as not to leave zombies hanging around. At some point near the beginning of the code, put

```
$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shell's background operator `&`:

```
system("some command &");
```