# End perl script without waiting for system call to return

Tags: linux, apache, perl, cgi

I'm running a simple apache web server on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) with a perl CGI script handling some requests. The script initiates a system command using the `system` function, but I want it to return immediately, regardless of the outcome of the system call.

I've been adding an ampersand to the end of the scalar argument passed to `system` (*I am aware of the implications of command injection attacks*) and although this does cause the system command to return immediately, the script will still not exit until the underlying command has completed.

If I trigger a dummy ruby script with a 10 second sleep using the `system` call from the perl CGI, then my request to the web server still waits 10 seconds before finally getting a response. I put a log statement after the `system` call and it appears immediately when the web request is made, so the `system` call is definitely returning immediately, but the script is still waiting at the end.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523543/how-do-i-make-a-system-call-and-resume-execution-without-waiting-for-the-call-to) is similar, but neither of the solutions have worked for me.

Here's some example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

Log::Log4perl->easy_init(
    { level => $DEBUG, file => ">>/var/log/script.log" } );

print "Content-type: application/json\n\n";
my $cgi = CGI->new();

INFO("Executing command...");
system('sudo -u on-behalf-of-user /tmp/test.rb one two &');
INFO("Command initiated - will return now...");

print '{"error":false}';
```

**Edit:**
The command call is executed using `sudo -u` because the apache user `www-data` needs permission to execute the script on behalf of the script owner, and I've updated my sudoers file appropriately to that end. This is not the cause of my issue, because I've also tried changing script ownership to `www-data` and running `system("/tmp/test.rb one two &")` but result is the same.

**Edit 2:**
I've also tried adding `exit 0` to the very end of the script, but it doesn't make any difference. Is it possible that the script is exiting immediately, but the apache server is holding onto the response until the script the perl CGI called is finished? Or is it possible that some setting or configuration of the operating system is causing the problem?

**Edit 3:**
Running the perl CGI script directly from a terminal works correctly. The perl script ends immediately, so this is not an inherent issue with Perl. Which presumably can only mean that the Apache web server is holding onto the request until the command called from `system` is finished. Why?

Comment: I know, they're almost identical, but in that Q I was asking specifically about the array version of the `system` call to prevent command injection. In any case, **none** of those solutions will work for me, resulting in the same behavior described in this question. Also, when I accepted the answer for that question, I wasn't properly testing so I didn't realize that it still wasn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web server creates a pipe from which to receive the response. It waits for the the pipe to reach EOF before completing the request. A pipe reaches EOF when all copies of the writer handle are closed.

The writer end of the pipe is set as the child's STDOUT. That file handle was copied to be the shell's STDOUT, and again to the `mycmd`'s STDOUT. So even though the CGI script and the shell ended and thus closed their ends of the file handle, `mycmd` still holds the handle open, so the web server is still waiting for the response to complete.

All you have to do with to close the last handle to the writer end of the pipe. Or more precisely, you can avoid making it in the first place by attaching a different handle to `mycmd` STDOUT.

```
mycmd arg1 arg2 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much, it works. I understand what your saying about the cause of the problem, but I'm not sure I understand the solution. Why does redirecting /dev/null to stdin, stdout and stderr solve the problem?

Comment: I have just improved the explanation in my answer.

Comment: So based on what you said, if the tree is chained by STDOUTs (writer is set to child's), why wouldn't redirecting the STDOUT be enough? Why the need for STDIN redirection? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @vol7ron, Providing a new STDIN is just common sense. Why would the child want to read from the pipe used by the web server to communicate the request to the CGI script? No good can came from that. As for STDERR, it's a pipe to the web server just like STDOUT.

Comment: Daemon::Daemonize shows what you normally want to do when creating a disjointed process. In this case, the shell handles the double-forking and creating the new session, leaving you the job of providing something for STD*.

Comment: I don't know what the child is doing so I couldn't speculate why it would or wouldn't. I'm just trying to clarify if not setting it would have any affect on the result (the delay).

Comment: STDIN? No, the web server doesn't wait for it to reach EOF since it's the writer.