# How can I handle a `system` call which fails?

Tags: windows, perl, error-handling, external

I have a Perl script which calls an external program. (Right now I'm actually using backticks, but I could just as easily use `system` or something from cpan.) Sometimes the program fails, causing Windows to create a dialog box "(external program) has stopped working" with the text

> Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...

shortly replaced with

> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

Unfortunately, this error message stops the process from dying, causing Perl to  not return until the user (me!) clicks "Cancel" or "Close Program". Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

In my use case it is acceptable to have the program fail -- it does useful but strictly not necessary work. But as it needs to run unattended I can't have it block the program's remaining work.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Perl, but can't you just caught this exception in a `try/catch` and then just show it in a popup window ?

Comment: @ValterHenrique: There's no exception to catch -- the program is still working as far as Perl knows.

Comment: Do you need to wait for the external program to finish running to continue?

Comment: @simbabque: That's the intent, yes. The next thing the script does relies on changes caused by the program.

Comment: Maybe check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646694/running-job-in-the-background-from-perl-without-waiting-for-return/2647237#2647237

Comment: @Mikitori: The script needs the program to run before it can continue (though it's possible to skip a small fraction of its invocations if they fail for some reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that backticks & `system` block while the external program is running/hanging.  Possible other aproaches might include.

- Using threads & various modules from the `Win32` family to busy-wait for the process end or click on the dialong box.  This is probably overkill.
- Use an Alarm Signal or Event to wake up your program when the external program has taken 'too long' to respond.
- Use an IPC Module to open the program and monitor it's progress.
- If you don't need the child program's return value, STDOUT or STDERR, simbabque's `exec` option has merit, but if you need to keep a handle on the process, try `Win32::Process`.  I've found this useful on many an occasion.  The module's `wait` method can be an excellent alternative to my Alarm suggestion or simabque's sleep suggestion with the added benefit that your program will not sleep longer than required by the child.

Comment: Blocking is the desired behavior. The script's next step depends on the external program's output. In a pinch it can be skipped, if it fails or just runs too long.

Comment: @Charles, that's why the 1st option might not fit for you, but waking up on occasion to see if the child is in a comma may not be the worst idea...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to wait for the external program to finish running to continue, you can do [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) instead of [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and it will never return.

You could always add a `sleep $n` afterwards to make it wait for the external program to theoretically finish.

```
exec('maybe_dies.exe');
sleep 1; # make sure it does stuff before it dies, or not, or whatever...
```

Comment: Huh? `exec` without `fork`? The docs say _"Since it's a common mistake to use exec instead of system, Perl warns you if exec is called in void context and if there is a following statement that isn't die, warn, or exit"_.

Comment: I guess that would be better so you don't get the warning. I will improve the answer latee. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Not sure whether `fork` really works on Windows. Plus: the OP wants blocking behaviour which makes `fork'n'exec` a bit more complicated.

Comment: That's why I naively put the sleep there. Forking as such works in Windows. I've used Parallel::FoekManager quite a bit at some point.